# Validation travis.yml file locally

Tags: validation, yaml, travis-ci

Are there any tools (CLI or with GUI) for validation travis.yml file locally at my computer without the need of pushing it? Maybe there are some plugins for text editors or other approaches to solve this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For validation of your .travis.yml without push it you can:

- Use **beta** online tool: https://config.travis-ci.com/explore
- Use command line validation from [Travis CI command line client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb) (it requires Ruby 1.9.3 and RubyGems):

To install ([documentation](https://support.travis-ci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002904174-Validating-travis-yml-files)):

```
$ gem install travis --no-document
```

To run the command line lint tool:

```
 $ travis lint [path to your .travis.yml]
```